# Spreading es6 import statements where they are used

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

In a js file that has no top-level code running, (it just exports functions), should every import statement be placed at the top of the file? Or can I spread them where they make more syntactic sense to me?

Does this affect performance and would you consider such code "hard to read"?

Example (all on top):

```js
import { multiply } from "./multiplication.js";
import { add } from "./addition.js";
import { toPower } from "./exponentiation.js";

export function computeMagicNumber(x, y, z) {
    let magic = linearOperation(x, y);
    magic = exponentOperation(magic, z);
    return magic;
}

function linearOperation(...) {
    // uses multiply() and add()
}

function exponentOperation(...) {
    // uses toPower()
}
```

Example (spread, so that it is closer to where it is used):

```js
export function computeMagicNumber(x, y, z) {
    let magic = linearOperation(x, y);
    magic = exponentOperation(magic, z);
    return magic;
}


import { multiply } from "./multiplication.js";
import { add } from "./addition.js";

function linearOperation(...) {
    // uses multiply() and add()
}


import { toPower } from "./exponentiation.js";

function exponentOperation(...) {
    // uses toPower()
}
```

Comment: What if you're using a import in the 2nd and in the 34th function in that file, where are you placing the import?

Generally, you _always_ put imports at the top of the file.

Comment: Placing imports at the top of functions is bad practice, makes it hard to tell the dependency graph. If you have imports needed only for some functions consider moving those function to a separate file.

Comment: @Cerbrus In that case I would put a common dependency at the top, yes. But when it is used once, what is your opinion?

Comment: _Always_ put them at the top., then you always know where to find them (and where to look to clean up redundant imports)

Comment: If you need something in just one function sometimes it's necessary to place the import inside the function to fix a circular dependency problem. However, I would never place a import above a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this affect performance?

No. The two modules work exactly the same.

> Would you consider such code "hard to read"?

Yes. The established best practice is to put imports at the top of the file, so that you don't have to search through the whole code for them. Also the imports will be evaluated first, before any code in the module, and will be available in the whole module scope, so it makes sense to declare them in linear order.

If you want your imports closer to the functions that use them, consider using smaller modules, i.e. putting each function in a separate module.